# Onion Router Raspberry use only Lan and not Wlan

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, raspberry-pi, tor

hello i have a tiny problem, i followd some tutorials, everything is working over the created wlan hotspot but i want change it thaht everything will goes over Lan, like the Raspi act as normal Router(i add the ip in the network settings of the device i want tunnel), i have no problem doing this with openvpn but on tor i failed

i tryt to change my currently comands to Eth0 but after i cant login to pi, so its seems not working

```
-A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 22
-A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 53
-A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9040
```

so my target is

Device->my local home network-> Raspberry in over eth0 -> Tor tunnel -> go out over eth0

Answer (score 0):

okay the solution was easyer then i was think

put this into /etc/tor/torrc

```
 Log notice file /var/log/tor/tor-notices.log
    VirtualAddrNetwork 10.192.0.0/10
    AutomapHostsSuffixes .onion,.exit
    AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
    TransPort 9040
    TransListenAddress 192.168.185.70
    DNSPort 53
    DNSListenAddress 192.168.185.70
```

the ip is my raspberryip

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.185.39 -i eth0 -p tcp --syn -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9040
```

i have to route only one linux device though tor so this enough for me